# Localization DevExpress

Tags: angular, devexpress

Eu estou tentando fazer a tradução dos componentes do DevExpress, ja entrei em contato com o suporte deles e parece que eles não estão afim de fazer um esforço pra ajudar...

Gostaria de saber se alguem aqui sabe por onde tenho que começar, quais arquivos eu preciso duplicar e traduzir e como fazer a modificação toda nos component/module (angular)...

*Estou me sujeitando a tomar downvote*
, mas preciso muito de um norte de como começar a fazer isso, estou perdido...

Tentei pelo intl e globalize, mas sempre ocorre erros, ou de nao pode achar o modulo:

Cant find module

'devextreme/localization/messages/de.json!json'
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ou tentando assim (no modulo):

```
messagesRu = require("devextreme/localization/messages/ru. json");
```

da erro falando:

cant find name 'require'